# CSS align nested element backgrounds with background-size:cover

Tags: css, background

I am planning to align the background on a button to the background on the body and blur out the button to create a frosty glass effect kinda thing.

But I can't get them to align properly.

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px
}

body{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:red;
 /*center the button*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  /*background image properties*/
  background-image:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/a5/cf/98a5cf91e8aef10a2b81303a7ccbce9e.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}

.button{
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  border-radius:10px;
  /*enter the f inside the box*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
 /*size of the f*/
  font-size:180px; 
  /*frosty glass effect*/
    
}

.position{
  position:relative;
  left:30px;
  top:24px;
  
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a class='button'><i class="fa fa-facebook position"></i></a>
```

The larger issue is I want a background image in the blue part aligned with the background behind it. Then blur out the blue background without blurring not white "f" logo.

The effect should be similar to this example image, except that the icon should not be translucent:

[image]

Comment: Very descriptive, very...  Could you provide an image for reference? Did you mean something like an alpha channel? (`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.33)`)

Answer (score 0):

I think `radial-gradient` with `rgba` colors can get close enough to the result

`background: radial-gradient(rgba(75, 212, 174, 0.95) 27%, rgba(77, 128, 191, 0.8) 77%)`

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  /*center the button*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*background image properties*/
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/a5/cf/98a5cf91e8aef10a2b81303a7ccbce9e.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(75, 212, 174, 0.95) 27%, rgba(77, 128, 191, 0.8) 77%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*enter the f inside the box*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*size of the f*/
  font-size: 180px;
  /*frosty glass effect*/
}

.position {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 24px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a class='button'><i class="fa fa-facebook position"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot align the two backgrounds using `cover`, since you would be unable to assume the precise size of the parent background in the child element of a different size.

If you want to keep using `cover`, your best bet is to simplify and use an alpha-channel background color like `background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);`

This will work to give you the transparent background color overlay, but without the blur effect.

---

For the "frosted glass" effect, there's a trick where you can align a background image and then blur it on the child element, which I think is what you're trying to accomplish.

You can do this if you're willing to nix the background cover in favor a set background size (like 100vw). You have to separate the content (white f) from the background that's blurred, since the blur affects everything inside the element. You'll also have to wrap it in a container with `overflow:hidden` in order to keep the sharp edges.

```css
*{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px
}

body{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/a5/cf/98a5cf91e8aef10a2b81303a7ccbce9e.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100vw;
}
.button-background, 
.button{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin:-100px 0 0 -100px;
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.button-background div{
  height:100%;
  background:url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/98/a5/cf/98a5cf91e8aef10a2b81303a7ccbce9e.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100vw;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.button{
  font-size:180px; 
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.position{
  position:absolute;
  right:30px;
  bottom:-15px;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class='button-background'><div></div></div>
<a class='button'><i class="fa fa-facebook position"></i></a>
```